# iOS BranchIO DeepLink returns nil value in launchOptions in AppDelete class

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io, deeplink

Prerequisites:

Create the iOS Application

1. Integrate the BranchIO pod and do required configurations as guided in link
   https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration
2. Generate the Deeplink from the backend
3. Tap on Deep-link will observer that launchOptions will be nil value

After integration of BranchIO into Swift iOS project,
Sometimes I am getting nil value to launchOptions?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      // listener for Branch Deep Link data
     Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { (params, error) in  
     // do stuff with deep link data (nav to page, display content, etc)
     print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: Could you observe any patterns as to in which cases you are not getting deep link data? You can check our sample application too - https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking-attribution/tree/master/Branch-TestBed

Comment: I have tried all the patterns but I observe that BranchIO is not picking the data at first time. If we try the same Deeplink multiple time(2nd or 3rd time) then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

launchOptions dictionary may be empty in situations where the user launched the app directly.

refer this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application

Is launchOptions nil when opening app from deeplink?